# Login redirecting to specific page based on specific group in template

Tags: django, django-admin-filters

I have two admin groups in django-admin[staff, student]. I want that whenever a user wants to log in, the program first checks that to which group the user belongs, then redirect each one to a particular page.

**index.html**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'users:login' %}" class="form">
{% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Log in</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
    
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'student_paper:index' %}" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think you should include your django view code here for better understanding

Comment: Actually, I have users app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom **`login_view`**:

Here's an example and also for more info see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in).

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_login_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        if user.is_staff:
            # Redirect to a success staff page.
        else:
            # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```